# How we can get the response back while calling stored procedure in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, error-handling

call temp(1, 1, 155823); When I run this query in my MySQL workbench, it gives me error like Subquery returns more than 1 row.

But when I call the exact same stored Procedure from my Laravel controller like -  $cropDetails = DB::select('call temp(1, 1, 155823)');
the request is keep sending and I am not getting any kind of response back.

I am using Laravel 6.20.32

while calling stored procedure form in Laravel, it should return something but the request is keep sending.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.